# PHP Special treatment on an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

`$firstArray = [
    'location', 'address', 'streetNumber'
];`

Extracted from that string variable :

```
$string = "location.address.streetNumber"
```

I would like get a value dynamically in an other array with these variables :

```
$value = $secondArray[$firstArray[0]][$firstArray[1]][$firstArray[2]];`
```

But without using keys directly ([0], [1], ...).

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about the data you have and any PHP code you are using? You've specified 0,1,2 - will 3,4,5 be another address? Or is that array populated each time on a foreach or similar?

Comment: I think he wants to do something like that : 
$myValue = $otherArray[$originalArray[0]][$originalArray[1]][$originalArray[2]]

Comment: Is there any value assigned to `location.address.street` ?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla no, it's for mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this do the work for you ?

```
$string = "location.address.streetNumber";

$firstArray = explode('.', $string);
$secondArray = ['location' => ['address' => ['streetNumber' => 'street 854']]];

$ref = &$secondArray;
foreach($firstArray as $val){
    $ref = &$ref[$val];
}

$value = $ref;
unset($ref);

echo $value // street 854
```

Comment: "location.address.streetNumber" is a exemple. I can have only 2 keys or 5. This must be managed dynamically.

Comment: it is.. in foreach try: `$string = "location.address";` and `var_dump` instead of `echo`

Comment: Yes sorry. In fact, my desired result is ['location']['address']['streetNumber']. Not access to the value.

Comment: i don't get it... sorry

Comment: I need to use ['location']['address']['streetNumber'] to browse another array. My objective is to create dynamically keys from values of $firstArray.

Comment: but whole thing is about getting value of array... ^^ this is happening already in foreach `$value === $secondArray['location']['address']['streetNumber']`

Comment: Thank's a lot ! 
I had misunderstood ...